# Data returned if GetItems if query did not match

Tags: sharepoint, spquery

This is really a simple question. What does `GetItems` method return if `SPQuery`object did not find any match? if i call the update method, if it did find anything. Will it add it?

I'm at the point of investigating a bug and I still don't have a environment for me to test and I'm new to SharePoint development so guys, please be gentle :D

Answer (score 0):

The item will be added anyway. It doesn't matter if there are any items in the `SPListItemCollection`.

`SPList.AddItem()` uses this behavior to avoid loading all of the items in the list. One could write:

```
SPList list = ...
list.Items.Add();
```

This loads all the items in the list, which might be slow for large item sets.

`SPList.AddItem()` retrieves the `SPListItemCollection` by executing a CAML query that returns no items (ID == -1) and calls then the `Add` method.